# iOS Category Inheritance to encapsulate NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I am attempting to encapsulate [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) methods in a `Category` on `NSObject` instead of repeating the [de]/serialization throughout the code.

#### .h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSObject (AYIAdditions)

+ (NSString *)JSONString;
+ (id)objectFromJSONString;
+ (id)objectFromJSONData;

@end
```

However, I am receiving the error: *No visible @interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'JSONString'*

`NSMutableDictionary` inherits `NSObject` and therefore should inherit these category methods, right? What am I missing?

As an aside, is using categories a good approach ([mentioned by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)). Or should I simply create an custom object with some class methods.

Comment: Are you `#import`-ing the header with the category in the file where the error occurs?

Comment: Have you imported the category header?

Comment: Yes. It is imported correctly.

Comment: Could you show us the code where you are getting the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code:

```
+ (NSString *)JSONString;
```

The `+` (Plus sign) indicates a class method. You most likely want an instance method, like so:

```
- (NSString *)JSONString;
```

**Regarding the methodology of how to implement serialization:** This is quite the "aside". The scope of what you are asking is very broad and you have given very few specifics. This is really a function of the scope of your needs and how much time/energy you want to invest, but to weigh-in an opinion:

A category on `NSObject` seems a bit overly-broad to me. I would think that it's unlikely to yield better results than, what seems like a more logical choice, a protocol.

I frankly wish `NSJSONSerialization` had declared a protocol for serializing our own custom model objects, similar to `NSCoding`, but they didn't. That's still generally the route I go when encoding object into `JSON`. A protocol could look something like this:

```
NSString * const MySerializationClassKey = @"MySerializationClassKey";
@protocol MySerializationProtocol <NSObject>
@required
-(NSDictionary *)dictionarySerialization;
-(id)initFromDictionarySerialization:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
@end
```

And then your custom model objects can serialize and de-serialize like this:(Overly simplistic)

```
@interface MyModel() <MySerializationProtocol>
@property (strong) NSString *name;
@end
@implementation MyModel
NSString * const MyModelNameKey = @"MyModelNameKey";
@synthesize name = _name;
-(NSDictionary *)dictionarySerialization{
    // encode object as dictionary
    return @{MySerializationClassKey: NSStringFromClass(self.class), MyModelNameKey: _name.copy};
}
-(id)initFromDictionarySerialization:(NSDictionary *)dictionary{
    if ((self = [super init])){
        _name = [dictionary objectForKey:MyModelNameKey];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Now suppose, for the sake of not typing a complete serialization library into an answer, that you only ever had a flat `NSArray` of these model objects. You could create a class that uses `NSJSONSerialization` in cooperation with these methods. To make each call easier, like so:

```
@interface MySerializer : NSObject
@end
@implementation MySerializer
+(NSData *)jsonDataFromObject:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < array.count; index++) {
        NSObject *object = [array objectAtIndex:index];
        if ([object conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MySerializationProtocol)]){
            NSDictionary *dictRep = [(id<MySerializationProtocol>)object dictionarySerialization];
            [array replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:dictRep];
        }
    }
    return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:0 error:nil];
}
+(NSMutableArray *)objectFromJSONData:(NSData *)data{
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < array.count; index++) {
        NSObject *object = [array objectAtIndex:index];
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
            NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)object;
            NSString *className = [dict objectForKey:MySerializationClassKey];
            if (className.length > 0) {
                NSObject *deserialized = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] initFromDictionarySerialization:dict];
                if (deserialized) [array replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:deserialized];
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
@end
```

Now obviously to get any mileage out of code like this you would have to recursively traverse the possible arrays and dictionaries. But this is my preferred route.

Comment: Doh! Just realized that myself. Any comments on my *aside*?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you did import the header for the category?

```
#import "NSObject+AYIAdditions.h"
```

Whether this is a correct approach or not is arguable. I don't think it is a good solution to add a method to `NSObject` which can't be called on all the objects (not all objects can be JSON-serialized).

Comment: Agreed. However, I am using `isValidJSONObject` to mitigate the concern.

Answer (score 0):

> You use the NSJSONSerialization class to convert JSON to Foundation
>   objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.
>
> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> - The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
> - All objects are
>     instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All
>     dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or
>     infinity. Other rules may apply.
>
> Calling `isValidJSONObject:` or
>   attempting a conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given
>   object can be converted to JSON data.<sub>source: [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)</sub>

so you should define that category on NSObject. a senseful place would be NSArray and NSDictionary.

I would also create a serializer class, that offers a `sharedSerializer`, that would be called from the both categories.

---

another approach could be to indeed declare the category on NSObject, but to pass in a failure block for handling of the case n objects wasnt serialize-able.

Comment: What's the purpose of `sharedSerializer` when `NSJSONSerialization` is already static?

Comment: first: there is no static class in objective-c. second: in the categories you define on NSArray and NSDictionary you only forward the method call to the same concrete implementation, where you can check if the object fulfills the requirements and than create the string.

Comment: Forgive me on the Objective-c semantics - *what's the purpose of `sharedSerializer` when `NSJSONSerialization` has only class methods?*